# Connecting vertices in different objects

Tags: faces

I'm trying to connect 2 adjacent vertices pairs to create 1 face, and using F does nothing. I think that's because the 2 vertices pairs are in 2 separate objects.

See the image -- the blue square is where I need the face to be.

How can that be done?

Thanks!!

[image: Image shows Object #1 on top, object #2 under it and the 2 vertice pairs that need to become a Face]

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly suspected, you can only create faces with vertices of the same object. Join the objects first, by selecting them in Object Mode and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. Then create the face by selecting the vertices and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.